# How do I implement radio buttons in Sitecore 7.5 page editor?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-mvc

I need to show the following admin section in the Sitecore 7.5 page editor above each page content. I want a content editor to be able to select one of these three radio button options and then have it persisted in Sitecore database once a user clicks to save the page. I cannot find online any example of how these radio buttons can be implemented in Sitecore 7.5 (MVC, if that matters). Any guidance will be highly appreciated.

**1/22/16 Update:**
Attention down-voters. I am not looking for the final code. I am looking for an advice on direction. Sitecore 7.5 doesn't even have the "radio button" data type available and I couldn't find any examples online. Thank you for understanding.

[image: access protection choice]

Comment: Have you tried anything already? Have you created any component in Sitecore MVC? Do you have any code we can help you with?

Comment: I've created the component, but I am outputting radio buttons as plain HTML `<input>` for now. I don't see even see a type in Sitecore that will allow us to render radio buttons on the page. I see one for a checkbox, but not the radio button. I've googled, but couldn't find any examples of similar implementation. I am just looking for a general direction at this point where to start.

Comment: The same in Sitecore 8.1. I am trying to add radio button list to custom rendering parameters, but there is no such type when you edit templates in sitecore...